# Get all crash reports from Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-console, firebase-crash-reporting

Firebase has very annoying interface to work with issues. There is no option to move to specific issue in cluster etc.

Is there any way to export crash reports from Firebase Crash Reporting section? Or may be you can give me a hint how to move to specific issue in cluster instead of clicking all issues one by one :).

Comment: I recommend adding these as two separate feature requests using this form: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/